# Gradle incremental build for my task: what's wrong?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, incremental-build

I'm struggling with Gradle 3.3 in Android Studio 2.3. I have assets generating task for which I specify inputs.dir and outputs.dir in cfg section:

```
task compileAssets{

inputs.dir 'src/main/assets_src' 
outputs.dir 'src/main/assets' 

def proj_src = 'src/main/'
def abs_proj_src = project.projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/' + 'src/main/'
abs_proj_src = abs_proj_src.replace('\\','/')

doLast {
    delete(proj_src + 'assets')
    mkdir(proj_src + 'assets')

    copy
        {
            from proj_src + 'assets_src'
            include 'xml/**'
            include 'fonts/**'
            include 'shaders/**'
            into proj_src + 'assets'
        }

    javaexec{
        main = '-jar'
        args = [
            "../../utils/encoder.jar",
            abs_proj_src + 'assets_src/bin/levels',
            abs_proj_src + 'assets/bin/levels',
            '-rewrite'
        ]
    }
}
```

I expect Gradle will check contents of input folder changes and if some files were added, removed or changed it will allow to execute task, else it will print 'UP-TO-DATE'. But it is so only when only delete(...) and mkdir(...). Otherwise it is executed every time. Maybe I understand the term 'incremental build' in a wrong way? Or maybe there is task size limit, or javaexec or copy are forbidden in incremental build?

PS. I tried to launch task with make command and directly from AS Gradle projects pane.

Answer (score 0):

It was my own error. Below is defined cleanAssets task, where I forgot to add << or doLast:

```
task cleanAssets{
        delete(proj_src + 'assets')
        mkdir(proj_src + 'assets')
}
```

So every build in configure phase assets folder was deleted. Funny!